# Sencha Touch App on iOS Simulator loads only index.html

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a problem in loading Sencha Touch on iOS simulator. When I integrated Sencha Touch on Phonegap and run it on simulator it worked charm. And also on the web it works fine, But only when I tried to run Sencha Touch directly on simulator it just loads the index.html page.  What could be the reason ?

Comment: Can you show us your index.html and describe your network/server architecture?

Comment: This is just a simple To-Do app and am new to sencha. index.html is same as what sencha generated for me. When run index.html on web it works perfect but only on simulator it just loads only index.html

Comment: You didn't tell us how you deliver (webserver?) the files. We cannot help you when you always tell us the same things.

Comment: Apple would never allow to disable web security on mobile safari. So files from my mac couldn't be loaded onto simulator. On mac safari I prompts to Allow or Deny access from file. This is not possible on simulator

Comment: hgoebl - Thanks for your time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple would never allow to disable web security on mobile safari. So files from my mac couldn't be loaded onto simulator. On mac safari I was prompted to Allow or Deny file access. But this is not possible on simulator